# org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext (MSC service thread 1-2) Error listenerStart

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I have a problem when I start my application in jboss server 
the stacktrace is:

```
18:00:56,869 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error listenerStart
18:00:56,870 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/application] startup failed due to previous errors
18:00:56,896 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./application: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./application: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:94)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
```

Comment: Can you please write about what you were trying to do? What commands you ran or a snippet of your code?

Comment: I try to start my java web application in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of project it is whether it's Maven or not. Just do this things hope it will help :

1. Goto Project -> Clean
2. If you are using maven project do a Maven clean & install.
3. Clean your server.
4. Remove already deployed item.
5. Restart your server.
   If still the problem persists checks if there is any service using that port or not.

Comment: yes it's a Maven project, i have already do all of this steps but the probleme still persists, which port should i check ?

Comment: Port 8080. If it did not help delete the server & install it again in eclipse!

Comment: If your machine have Apache Tomcat installed try with that or else look @service if its running in background blocking the port 8080.

Comment: i am using a Jboss server, it's not a port probleme for more détails, i have added à Spring SAML extension so the problem was appeared.